# Nort sure about error in Number Stream Coderbyte Java

Tags: java

The problem:
Have the function NumberStream(str) take the str parameter being passed which will contain the numbers 2 through 9, and determine if there is a consecutive stream of digits of at least N length where N is the actual digit value. If so, return the string true, otherwise return the string false. For example: if str is "6539923335" then your program should return the string true because there is a consecutive stream of 3's of length 3. The input string will always contain at least one digit.

Error message:
Main.java:29: error: '.class' expected
if (temp.length()>1 && char(temp.length() + 48 == temp[0])
^
Main.java:29: error: ';' expected
if (temp.length()>1 && char(temp.length() + 48 == temp[0])

Can anyone help solve this errors? I am new to Java

My solution:

```
mport java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String NumberStream(String str) {
    // code goes here
    if (str.length()==1)
    {
            return "false";
    } 
    string temp = "";
    temp +=str[0];
    for (int x =1; x<str.length();x++)
    {
      if (temp.empty())
      {
        temp.push_back(str[x]);
        continue;
      }
      if (str[x] ==temp[0])
      {
        temp +=str[x];
      }
      else
      {
        temp.clear();
      }
      if (temp.length()>1 && char(temp.length() + 48 == temp[0])
      {
        return "true";     
      }
    }
    return "false";
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(NumberStream(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up array and String syntax. There is no `[index]` notation for String in Java, you need to use `charAt`. Also, Java is case-sensitive, you must uses `String`, not `string`.

I've also fixed some other things, like a missing parens, and the conversion to `char`.

```java
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static String numberStream(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 1)
        {
            return "false";
        } 
        String temp = "";
        temp += str.charAt(0);
        for (int x = 1; x < str.length(); x++)
        {
            if (temp.length() == 0)
            {
                temp = temp + str.charAt(x);
                continue;
            }
            if (str.charAt(x) == temp.charAt(0))
            {
                temp += str.charAt(x);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = "";
            }
            if (temp.length() > 1 && (char) (temp.length() + 48) == temp.charAt(0))
            {
                return "true";         
            }
        }
        return "false";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {    
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(numberStream(s.nextLine())); 
    }
}
```

Also note that your code seems to be wrong for the input `"1"` --- shouldn't that get a "true"? Your code prints "false".

You could also use Java's [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) function to find a String in a String:

```
public class Main {
    public static String consecutiveDigits(String s) {
        String[] digitStrings = {"1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555", "666666", "7777777", "88888888", "999999999"};
        for (String digits : digitStrings) {
            if (s.indexOf(digits) > -1) {
                return "true";
            }
        }
        return "false";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {    
        for (String a : args) {
            System.out.println(a + ": " + consecutiveDigits(a));
        }
    }
}
```

This version of the code takes the test inputs on the command line (this makes it easier to run the previous command without having to type all the inputs again):

```
java Main.java 33345 3456 1234 2342255897
33345: true
3456: false
1234: true
2342255897: true
```